# Flink Stream, how to read file incrementally?

Tags: apache-flink

I've set up my very first toy Flink, I want to do a very simple thing: continuously read a local file and print the content.

The problem is, each time I update that local file, Flink print all lines, I want it to only print the newly added lines.

Code snippet:

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
String path = "/home/foobar/input";
TextInputFormat inputFormat = new TextInputFormat(new Path(path));
inputFormat.setCharsetName("UTF-8");
DataStreamSource<String> ds = env.readFile(inputFormat, path,
                FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY, 60000l, BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO);
ds.print();
env.execute("jobname02");
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, this is the [documented](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/datastream_api.html#data-sources) behavior of the PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY mode:

> If the watchType is set to FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY,
>   when a file is modified, its contents are re-processed entirely. This
>   can break the “exactly-once” semantics, as appending data at the end
>   of a file will lead to all its contents being re-processed.

This mode is more useful when applied to a directory, into which you atomically move files once they have been completely written.

Comment: Thank you David, I totally missed that part of the doc. I just set the path to a directory, then moved file one by one into it, it works like what you say. But I still curious to know if there is a way to read a single file incrementally, do you have any idea?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of any way to do that. You could use a socket instead, but then you can't rewind and replay, which breaks flink's approach to fault tolerance.